# Spring Social Linkedin resourceaccessexception

Tags: spring, linkedin-api, spring-social

I am trying to use social linkedin to do profiles simple search. I have settup my config and everything, but I get an exception when I am trying to search. Here is my code:

context.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.social.linkedin.connect.LinkedInServiceProvider">
        <constructor-arg value="75........" /> // Api Token
        <constructor-arg value="Fl2........" /> //secret
    </bean>
```

I use it as follows:

```
    @Autowired LinkedInServiceProvider provider;

  .........
LinkedIn ln = provider.getApi("AQW......."); //My accessToken
        SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
        searchParameters.setFirstName("firsname");
        searchParameters.setLastName("lastname");
ln.profileOperations().search(searchParameters);
```

When I hit the search, I get an exception:

```
2016-04-07 09:35:25,727 [ERROR] [io.undertow.request] (default task-11) UT005023: Exception handling request to /springsocial/home: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:980) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at controllers.HeadRequestsFilter.doFilter(HeadRequestsFilter.java:60) [classes:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174) [undertow-servlet-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793) [undertow-core-1.3.11.Final.jar:1.3.11.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken": Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:607) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:557) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:357) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2Template.postForAccessGrant(OAuth2Template.java:242) [spring-social-core-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2Template.authenticateClient(OAuth2Template.java:197) [spring-social-core-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar:1.1.4.RELEASE]
    at controllers.Entry.home2(Entry.java:49) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968) [spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173) [jsse.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153) [rt.jar:1.8.0_66]
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 54 more
```

Any idea why I hit this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was behind a proxy. I resolved this by adding application arguments:

-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080